# Is there any known LWC "real-life" practice exercises besides trailhead superbadges?

Tags: lightning-web-components, trailhead, learning

**Hi people! I'm on my path to Dev I certification, and I wonder if there's a recommended site, bootcamp or whatever resource besides

> Process Automation Specialist (Superbadge)
> Apex Specialist (Superbadge)
> Build a Bear-Tracking App with Lightning Web Components (Project)

to practice challenging Lightning web components development but yet focused on "noobs" like me?? The point of this question is to create a custom trailmix with excercises that are a little bit challenging than novice ones and real-life simulated, but focused on begginer developers. Other projects that I'm unaware of are greatly welcome.**

Comment: Dev I is more about knowing when to use code, than using code. If you've done the superbadges I'd say book the test!

Answer (score 2):

As far as Platform Developer I, if you've gotten through [the requirements](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/platformdeveloperi), you should have all the skills you need to pass the exam. It's honestly a pretty easy test if you didn't struggle too much with the preparatory work. The official stuff is on Trailhead.

However, if you really want to take your LWC to the next level, consider learning JavaScript really well, such as on [The Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info/). You won't use it on PD I, but you'll be able to write higher-quality code than your peers. Build yourself a portfolio and host it on [WebComponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev).

If you're looking to challenge yourself, try being creative and come up with your own. For example, you might try writing a calendar app, or a simple file management app, or whatever. Choose something you know you haven't done yet, but you think you might be able to. Tutorials and random Internet challenges will only get you so far. You need to blaze your own trail.